# Accessing mobile phone features from jsp designed using jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have this idea to open a page (designed using jquerymobile ) hosted in a server from index.html in Cordova and from there on all the logic will take place on the server side and all the resulting views designed in jquery mobile will be shown on the phone to act as a native app.

for example below is the index.html in cordova that is shown when the app starts:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script> window.open("http://localhost:8080/xyz.jsp")</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

As soon as app starts it will redirect to xyz.jsp, in which i will have the UI designed in jquery mobile. So the view that the mobile user will get will be that of a native app. The new jsp won't open in a mobile browser. It will be seen just as a part of mobile app. This I have tested already.

My question arises here, 
When i have redirected from index,html to the jsp that is hosted on some server I am able to get the view in the form of mobile app (because of jquery mobile) but

Will I be able to use mobile phone features from this jsp using jquery mobile or some other way ?